# Suppress stdout / stderr print from Python functions

Tags: python, stdout

I have a Python script that is using some closed-box Python functions (i.e. I can't edit these functions) provided by my employer. When I call these functions, they are printing output to my linux terminal that I would like to suppress. I've tried redirecting stdout / stderr via;

```
orig_out = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StringIO()
rogue_function()
sys.stdout = orig_out
```

but this fails to catch the output. I think the functions I'm calling via-Python (rogue_function() from above) are really wrappers for compiled C-code, which are actually doing the printing.

Does anyone know of a way I can do a "deep-capture" of any print handed to stdout / stderr by a function (and any sub-functions that function calls)?

**UPDATE**:

I ended up taking the method outlined in the selected answer below and writing a context manager to supress stdout and stderr:

```
# Define a context manager to suppress stdout and stderr.
class suppress_stdout_stderr(object):
    '''
    A context manager for doing a "deep suppression" of stdout and stderr in 
    Python, i.e. will suppress all print, even if the print originates in a 
    compiled C/Fortran sub-function.
       This will not suppress raised exceptions, since exceptions are printed
    to stderr just before a script exits, and after the context manager has
    exited (at least, I think that is why it lets exceptions through).      

    '''
    def __init__(self):
        # Open a pair of null files
        self.null_fds =  [os.open(os.devnull,os.O_RDWR) for x in range(2)]
        # Save the actual stdout (1) and stderr (2) file descriptors.
        self.save_fds = [os.dup(1), os.dup(2)]

    def __enter__(self):
        # Assign the null pointers to stdout and stderr.
        os.dup2(self.null_fds[0],1)
        os.dup2(self.null_fds[1],2)

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        # Re-assign the real stdout/stderr back to (1) and (2)
        os.dup2(self.save_fds[0],1)
        os.dup2(self.save_fds[1],2)
        # Close all file descriptors
        for fd in self.null_fds + self.save_fds:
            os.close(fd)
```

To use this you just:

```
with suppress_stdout_stderr():
    rogue_function()
```

This works "pretty good". It does suppress the printout from the rogue functions that were cluttering up my script. I noticed in testing it that it lets through raised exceptions as well as some logger print, and I'm not entirely clear why. I think it has something to do with *when* these messages get sent to stdout / stderr (I think it happens after my context manager exits). If anyone can confirm this, I'd be interested in hearing the details ...

Comment: Does [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/978264/344821) (from the related sidebar) work?

Comment: Instead of setting `sys.stdout` to `StringIO()`, have you tried setting it to a file?  i.e. `sys.stdout = open('log.txt','w')`

Comment: Dougal, thanks, that looks promising, I'll try it out tomorrow. nullpointer, I tried directing it to a custom NullPointer() class, and that didn't work either.

Comment: @Dougal, thanks, that worked! If you're so inclined, post that link as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to suppress *all* output, not just the output that comes from C code. I would expect that if I'm in the context __with suppress_stdout_stderr()__ then all output should be intercepted. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note that I edited this snippet slightly so all file descriptors are closed in `__exit__`. Without closing the fd's in `self.save_fds` this context manager was leaking two file descriptors every time it was called leading to running out of file descriptors in long running processes.

Comment: does this solution works when 'rogue_function' processed in parallel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647498/how-to-close-file-descriptors-in-python  -> @randlet should we also edit to close the save_fds ones?

Comment: @shaneb  they're already closed as well: `for fd in self.null_fds + self.save_fds:`

Comment: @randlet - ah, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978264/344821) (found through the related sidebar) might work. It reassigns the file descriptors rather than just the wrappers to them in sys.stdout, etc.

Answer (score 37):

As of python 3.5 we can do this with minimal work using built-ins in [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html), namely [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) and [`redirect_stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr). We only need to combine these two built-in context managers in a custom context manager of ours, which can be easily done using [the nice pattern in Martijn's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681273/5067311). Redirecting both outputs to [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.devnull) should be safe and portable enough.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager,redirect_stderr,redirect_stdout
from os import devnull

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout_stderr():
    """A context manager that redirects stdout and stderr to devnull"""
    with open(devnull, 'w') as fnull:
        with redirect_stderr(fnull) as err, redirect_stdout(fnull) as out:
            yield (err, out)
```

---

Note that suppressing `stderr` will still give you full tracebacks when something breaks, which is a good thing:

```
import sys

def rogue_function():
    print('spam to stdout')
    print('important warning', file=sys.stderr)
    1 + 'a'
    return 42

with suppress_stdout_stderr():
    rogue_function()
```

When run the above only prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 20, in <module>
    rogue_function()
  File "foo.py", line 16, in rogue_function
    1 + 'a'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

to the terminal. Unhandled exceptions should never go unnoticed.

Comment: This was the easiest thing to get working for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

python 3.6 working version, tested with million suppressions without any errors

```
import os
import sys

class suppress_stdout_stderr(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.outnull_file = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        self.errnull_file = open(os.devnull, 'w')

        self.old_stdout_fileno_undup    = sys.stdout.fileno()
        self.old_stderr_fileno_undup    = sys.stderr.fileno()

        self.old_stdout_fileno = os.dup ( sys.stdout.fileno() )
        self.old_stderr_fileno = os.dup ( sys.stderr.fileno() )

        self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.old_stderr = sys.stderr

        os.dup2 ( self.outnull_file.fileno(), self.old_stdout_fileno_undup )
        os.dup2 ( self.errnull_file.fileno(), self.old_stderr_fileno_undup )

        sys.stdout = self.outnull_file        
        sys.stderr = self.errnull_file
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):        
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr

        os.dup2 ( self.old_stdout_fileno, self.old_stdout_fileno_undup )
        os.dup2 ( self.old_stderr_fileno, self.old_stderr_fileno_undup )

        os.close ( self.old_stdout_fileno )
        os.close ( self.old_stderr_fileno )

        self.outnull_file.close()
        self.errnull_file.close()
```

Comment: I found this more reliable than the top voted answer.  The top voted answer did not suppress stdout and stderr coming from underlying c++ and c libraries.  This did.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to redirect stderr too?
e.g.

```
sys.stdout = StringIO()
sys.stderr = StringIO()
foo(bar)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ # These are provided by python
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Also using StringIO might use extra memory. You can use a dummy device instead (e.g. http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/05/python-redirect-or-turn-off-stdout-and.html).

Comment: It might be that the C code is writing directly to stdout; you probably wouldn't be able to redirect that. Sorry.

Comment: Are these compatible with Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to yours but uses `contextlib` and is a little shorter and easier to understand (IMHO).

```python
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdchannel_redirected(stdchannel, dest_filename):
    """
    A context manager to temporarily redirect stdout or stderr

    e.g.:


    with stdchannel_redirected(sys.stderr, os.devnull):
        if compiler.has_function('clock_gettime', libraries=['rt']):
            libraries.append('rt')
    """

    try:
        oldstdchannel = os.dup(stdchannel.fileno())
        dest_file = open(dest_filename, 'w')
        os.dup2(dest_file.fileno(), stdchannel.fileno())

        yield
    finally:
        if oldstdchannel is not None:
            os.dup2(oldstdchannel, stdchannel.fileno())
        if dest_file is not None:
            dest_file.close()
```

The context for why I created this is at [this blog post](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2013/07/19/python-context-manager-for-redirected-stdout-and-stderr/). Similar to yours I think.

I use it like this in a `setup.py`:

```python
with stdchannel_redirected(sys.stderr, os.devnull):
    if compiler.has_function('clock_gettime', libraries=['rt']):
        libraries.append('rt')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really requested by the OP, but I needed to hide *and store* the output, and did like follows:

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

class Hider:
    def __init__(self, channels=('stdout',)):
        self._stomach = StringIO()
        self._orig = {ch : None for ch in channels}

    def __enter__(self):
        for ch in self._orig:
            self._orig[ch] = getattr(sys, ch)
            setattr(sys, ch, self)
        return self

    def write(self, string):
        self._stomach.write(string)

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def autopsy(self):
        return self._stomach.getvalue()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        for ch in self._orig:
            setattr(sys, ch, self._orig[ch])
```

Usage:

```
with Hider() as h:
    spammy_function()
    result = h.autopsy()
```

(tested only with Python 3)

**EDIT:** now allows to select `stderr`, `stdout` or both, as in `Hider([stdout, stderr])`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for python 3 ! one could also add seld._stderr == sys.stderr; sys.stderr = self <...>

Answer (score 1):

I use a decorator for this. It saves `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` references and makes these variables point to null. Then, after the function execution the original references are retrieved. It is important to note the try/except block, that allows the retrieval of the original references even when an exception is raised on the function.

```
def suppress_std(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        stderr_tmp = sys.stderr
        stdout_tmp = sys.stdout
        null = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        sys.stdout = null
        sys.stderr = null
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            sys.stderr = stderr_tmp
            sys.stdout = stdout_tmp
            return result
        except:
            sys.stderr = stderr_tmp
            sys.stdout = stdout_tmp
            raise
    return wrapper
```

To use:

```
@suppress_std
def function_std_suppressed():
    # code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Linux/Unix:

```
./myscript.py 2>/dev/null # gets rid of stderr
./myscript.py 2>/somewhere/myerror.log
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you answer to old questions (this one is over 8 year old) that have already an accepted answer (that's the case here): Please check if you really have a substantial improvement to offer. If not, don't answer. (Your answer was already given.)

Answer (score -2):

If you are running this script on a linux based machine, you should be able to:

```
$> ./runscript.py > output.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to suppress all output generated by the script, only the spurious output generated by these particular functions. Otherwise, yeah, this would be the simplest solution ...

Comment: Would this help: Add a print before and after those particular function. Parse the output with a regex to get rid of everything between the prints added above