# Error Message Using numpy.polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy.polyfit and the following error occurs:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD.
C:\Users\Max.Kaye\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py:594: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned 
warnings.warn(msg, RankWarning)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: Perhaps see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173301/numpy-polyfit-suppress-printing-of-intel-mkl-error-message). Particularly @Nim J's comment saying that your error  "occurs when you have Nan or Inf value in your input. Please check and impute it."

Comment: That said, to better answer it may be necessary to see the code around your call to polyfit.

Comment: The problem is that I want the result to write to a csv file, but it merely returns blanks when doing so. The code is part of a loop so I shall try and extract the eronous entries today