# Getting LinAlgError("SVD did not converge") when tensorflow imported to Keras skript

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting the following error when tensorflow is imported:

> Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to DLASCL.
>
> Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to DLASCL.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/xxx/skript.py", line 25, in
>   
>       h1 = LSTM(50)(input1)   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py",
>   line 268, in **call**
>       return super(Recurrent, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 575, in **call**
>       self.build(input_shapes[0])
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py",
>   line 1034, in build
>       constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 87, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 396, in add_weight
>       weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/initializers.py",
>   line 247, in **call**
>       u, _, v = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py",
>   line 1389, in svd
>       u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
>   File "/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py",
>   line 99, in _raise_linalgerror_svd_nonconvergence
>       raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge") numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

With a generic skript, which you can also use for testing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
import numpy as np    


# Length of sequence.
sequence_length = 300
# Number of base features 
num_features = 15
# Number of events 
num_event_features = 20

# Input 
input1 = Input(shape=(sequence_length, num_features))
# Build first LSTM on the first input.
h1 = LSTM(50)(input1)

# Apply the dense layer for prediction.
prediction = Dense(1)(h1)

# Define the keras model.
model = Model(inputs=[input1], outputs=[prediction])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate some random data for testing.
X1 = np.random.rand(1000, sequence_length, num_features).astype(np.float32)    
Y = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000).astype(np.float32)

# Train the model on random data.
model.fit(x=[X1], y=Y)
```

If i delete the import tensorflow as tf the network will be trained without a error message. I am using Keras 2.0.8, python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.3.0.
Tensorflow was installed for Ubuntu, python 3.6 and GPU support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, after installing mkl-service. Uninstalling it solved it for me.

Comment: another way is to downgrade it to     conda install mkl==11.3.3, described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669870/keras-with-tensorflow-backend-on-gpu-mkl-error-parameter-4-was-incorrect-on-en

Comment: Downgrading mkl didn't work for us. Uninstalling mkl-service did though!