# Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry

Tags: python, scipy, intel-mkl

I get the following error:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD.
```

when running a Savistky-Golay filter on scipy (function `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`).

I tried to uninstall conda using anaconda-clean, after which I did this:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/intel-math-kernel-library-mkl-error-using-python-6fbe9cf4aa4e

Didn't solve the problem. Still no idea what is going on, I'd really love to know what I can do. Also, my data does not contain nans.

I am using spyder 4.2.0 and python 3.7.9 on windows 10, running the script in an external window. Not sure if this is related, but I am using the `multiprocessing` package and the call to `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` is in a function called by a pool of workers (minimal example below):

```
def fn_savgol(x, window_length, polyorder):
    # some stuff
    result = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(x, window_length, polyorder)
    # some other stuff updating the result
    return result

def backtest_single_combi(args):
    p=multiprocessing.Pool()
    print("Start Pool.")
    result=p.imap_unordered(fn_savgol,args)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return list(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args=(...) # a list of tuples
    backtest_single_combi(args)
```

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error and solved it by [adding the intel channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html#managing-channels) to the top of the conda channel list and followed with an update.

```
conda config --add channels intel
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The only workaround I found is to change the `mode` parameter from default value ('interp') to either 'mirror' or 'constant' or 'nearest' or 'wrap'.