# Intel MKL ERROR when callyng Python from Matlab

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, intel-mkl

I've always been working in Python but now I have to share a function with a colleague working in Matlab. Since the thing is quite complex, calls compiled C code, etc. I thought it was easier to just call the Python code from Matlab.

Everything seems fine up to this line:
`points = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, correlation, nSamples)`

I get the errors:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 12 was incorrect on entry to DGBBRDM.

Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 10 was incorrect on entry to DGESDD.
init_gesdd failed init
```

and the execution continues smoothly with points being an array of **zeroes**.

Of course when running the Python code directly (from the same conda env) I get my multivariate normal sample.

Searching around and here I find only solutions that mention how the code was compiled, how it links and the interface that may be C or Fortran. In here I didn't compile anything, and I don't understand why the intermediate Matlab step should mess with the libraries used by numpy.

I found something related on the [Anaconda guide](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed), but seems Windows specific and mentions different software than Matlab, so I'm not even sure is the same problem.

An answer to a (maybe) similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304879/intel-mkl-error-parameter-6-was-incorrect-on-entry) suggested

```
conda config --add channels intel
conda update --all
```

but this didn't help either.

Overall it doesn't seem a convenient way to share some function with a colleague....

### Edit

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and, if it matters, is running on 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8, Python 3.9.12, MatlabR2022b.

2 steps to reproduce:

- file `testMatlabIntel.py` contains:

  ```py
    import numpy as np
    def test():
        means = [0,0]
        correlation = [[1,0.3],[0.3,1]]
        nSamples = 300
        points = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, correlation, Samples)
        return np.std(points)
  ```
- open Matlab from the terminal, if needed add the path to the python file in the python path (`insert(py.sys.path,int32(0),'path/to/file');`) then run:

  ```matlab
    py.testMatlabIntel.test()
  ```

  The output in the Matlab prompt is:

  ```matlab
    /path/to/file/testMatlabIntel.py:7: RuntimeWarning: covariance is not positive-semidefinite.
      points = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, correlation, Samples)

    ans =

         0
  ```

  while on the terminal I used to launch Matlab I see:

  ```bash
    Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 12 was incorrect on entry to DGBBRDM.

    Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 10 was incorrect on entry to DGESDD.
  ```

Note that is not just an array with zero variance but an array of zeros.

By contrast on a different machine (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8) I get simply:

```matlab
  ans =

      1.0136
```

and no warning as calling the test function from Python and as expected from a unitary variance sample.

### Edit 2

Machine running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS:

```
    Python: 3.9.16 (main, Feb 22 2023, 02:08:36) 
    [GCC 11.2.0]

    Numpy: 1.23.5

    MKL: Intel(R) oneAPI Math Kernel Library Version 2023.1-Product Build 20230303 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
```

I double-checked that the same version is called both from the terminal and Matlab.

From the terminal, when calling Python I get `[GCC 11.2.0] :: Intel Corporation on linux`

Also, setting `MKL_VERBOSE=1` it prints:

```
    MKL_VERBOSE DGESDD(A,8589934594,8589934594,0x7fbfc9a789b0,8589934594,0x7fbfc9a789d0,0x7fbfc9a789e0,8589934594,0x7fbfc9a78a00,-4294967294,0x7fc12b3f9010,1382979469311,0x7fbfc9a78a20,-10) 580.03us CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  NThr:4
    init_gesdd failed init
    MKL_VERBOSE DGEMM(N,T,2,2,2,0x7fc12b3fabc0,0x7fbfc9a991e0,2,0x7fbfc9a97600,2,0x7fc12b3fabc8,0x7fbfc9685760,2) 131.85us CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  NThr:4
    MKL_VERBOSE DGEMM(N,N,2,300,2,0x7fc12b3fabc0,0x7fbfc9685760,2,0x7fc05d198a00,2,0x7fc12b3fabc8,0x7fc05d199cd0,2) 15.14us CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  NThr:4
```

If this can be of any help.

On the other machine (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS), from inside Matlab I get:

```
    Python: 3.9.16 (main, Mar  8 2023, 14:08:28) 
    [GCC 11.2.0]
    
    Numpy: 1.23.5

    MKL: Intel(R) oneAPI Math Kernel Library Version 2023.1-Product Build 20230303 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
```

From the terminal, when calling Python I get `[GCC 11.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux`

Summarising:

|  | works | doesn't |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ubuntu | 20.04.6 LTS | 22.04.2 LTS |
| Matlab | R2023a | R2022b |
| Python | 3.9.16 | 3.9.16 |
| From INTEL? | No? | Yes |
| Numpy | 1.23.5 | 1.23.5 |
| MKL | 2023.1 | 2023.1 |

Comment: Could you please let us know the OS details, sample reproducer code and complete steps you have followed to investigate more on your issue?

Comment: @Varsha-Intel, I hope this is what you asked. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify the exact Intel MKL and numpy versions you are using? Could you please confirm whether you are using Intel Python or Stock Python? And also, please confirm whether Python version you are using is the same on both machines(Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @Varsha-Intel, sorry if it took a while. I'll add the other Matlab version as soon as I get back to that machine. Besides the OS, the only differences seem to be the Matlab version and that the one that's not working is Intel... unless Anaconda is Intel as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485995/intel-mkl-error-when-callying-scipy-from-matlab). The solution was to add the following line to the start up file:

```
py.sys.setdlopenflags(int32(bitor(int64(py.os.RTLD_LAZY),int64(py.os.RTLD_DEEPBIND))));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It worked! Please @TooManyQuestionsInLife add it as a solution/fix also to your previous question as I came across it but I had to ask again))