# Intel MKL ERROR when calling SciPy function from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, intel-mkl

I am using Matlab R2023a on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. This line in MATLAB

```matlab
py.scipy.special.roots_jacobi(int8(8),1,1)
```

produces the error message

> "Python Error: ValueError: illegal value in argument 11 of internal sbevd

In the terminal where I called MATLAB, I have the error

> Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 11 was incorrect on entry to DSBEVD.

Calling this function directly in Python does not yield this error. How can I use this Python function from within MATLAB?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding the following line to the startup file:

```matlab
py.sys.setdlopenflags(int32(bitor(int64(py.os.RTLD_LAZY), int64(py.os.RTLD_DEEPBIND))));
```