# How to close file descriptors in python?

Tags: python-2.7, file, unix, stdout

I have the following code in python:

```
import os


class suppress_stdout_stderr(object):
    '''
    A context manager for doing a "deep suppression" of stdout and stderr in
    Python, i.e. will suppress all print, even if the print originates in a
    compiled C/Fortran sub-function.
       This will not suppress raised exceptions, since exceptions are printed
    to stderr just before a script exits, and after the context manager has
    exited (at least, I think that is why it lets exceptions through).

    '''
    def __init__(self):
        # Open a pair of null files
        self.null_fds = [os.open(os.devnull,os.O_RDWR) for x in range(2)]
        # Save the actual stdout (1) and stderr (2) file descriptors.
        self.save_fds = (os.dup(1), os.dup(2))

    def __enter__(self):
        # Assign the null pointers to stdout and stderr.
        os.dup2(self.null_fds[0],1)
        os.dup2(self.null_fds[1],2)

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        # Re-assign the real stdout/stderr back to (1) and (2)
        os.dup2(self.save_fds[0],1)
        os.dup2(self.save_fds[1],2)
        # Close the null files
        os.close(self.null_fds[0])
        os.close(self.null_fds[1])

for i in range(10**6):
    with suppress_stdout_stderr():
        print 'plop'
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print i
```

it fails at 5100 on OSX with `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`. I'm wondering why and if there is a solution to close the file descriptor. I'm looking for a solution for a context manager which closes stdout and stderr.

Comment: Normally one would use `f = open(...); f.close()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I executed your code on a Linux machine and got the same error but at a different number of iterations.
I added the following two lines in the `__exit__(self, *_)` function of your class:

`os.close(self.save_fds[0])
os.close(self.save_fds[1])`

With this change I do not get an error and the script returns successfully. I assume that the duplicated file descriptors stored in `self.save_fds` are kept open if you don't close them with `os.close(fds)` and so you get the too many files open error.
Anyway my console printed "plop", but maybe this depends on my platform. 
Let me know if it works :)