# Python log-the-display problems

Tags: python, logging, scipy, io-redirection

I'm trying to log the terminal display produced by a script which contains a Scipy optimization routine.  I've tried three different ways, all with disappointing results.

open() and cmd-prompt redirection (">") did not log the warnings nor the per-iteration information I would like to keep track of; it only logged the parameter solutions.

logging.basicConfig() produced a blank file.

If possible, I would like to be able to log the exact terminal display of a script file.  I've begun looking into using the logging module, but it seems pretty complex for what I would think is a very basic task (I'm coming from a Matlab background).

Environment:

. Python 2.7.3

. Operating Systems: Windows Vista and XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the stuff you're interested in is being sent to stderr rather than stdout. Try redirecting both to a file.  You can either do that in Python:

```
import sys

with open("log.txt", "w") as logfile:
    sys.stdout, sys.stderr = logfile, logfile

    # do your stuff here, e.g. import the module that you want to log
```

Or from the command line:

```
python myscript.py > log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: The first method might not work if some scipy code prints from C(++) rather than going through Python printing channels (which is possible, idk). [This approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/978264/344821) gets around that on Unix; not sure if it works on Windows.

Comment: Good point. You could of course use `subprocess` to run a separate Python instance and get around that, but at that point it's going to be easier to do it with the command line...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at linux [script](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_script.htm) command. It saves everything that is printed in your terminal.

```
user@host:~ $ script
Script started, file is typescript
user@host:~ $ ls
bin  Documents  Pictures  Videos
user@host:~ $ exit # ^D stops script
Script done, file is typescript
```

Then, the result is in a file named `typescript`.

Comment: Sorry, did not see It was a Windows environment.