# How do I capture stderr in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to capture error messages which are generated from a python module `A`. `A` is written in C++ and SWIG, and so I cannot capture Python's `sys.stderr`.

```
>>> import A
>>> A.func() # this prints an error message by C++ std::cerr.
this is an error message from module A
```

What I want to do are to suppress the error message and to change my script behavior according to the error type. But `A.func()` does not return error numbers.

---

Assuming that my use of contextlib below is correct, it did not help.

```
>>> import io
>>> f = io.StringIO()
>>> import contextlib
>>> with contextlib.redirect_stderr(f):
... no_return = A.func()
ERROR MESSAGE HERE
>>> f.getvalue()

>>>
```

Comment: why not use a try statement ?

Comment: @gogaz That would still not catch output written to `std::cerr` or would it?

Comment: Does `contextlib redirect_stdout` work for you? In that case, this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr

Comment: It didn't work. I should have mentioned it. I will edit the original post.

Comment: You will need to mess with its low-level file descriptor to get at the real stderr. See the stuff about file descriptors in the os module docs, and check out this article about redirecting C-level stdout in Python. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/#id1

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753573/4014959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @PM2Ring

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/#id1

With minor modifications: replacing all the `stdout` with `stderr` and supporting macOS as shown below, it worked perfectly as expected.

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    c_stderr = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, '__stderrp')
else:
    c_stderr = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stderr')
```